# How to find the complex roots of $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> How to find the complex roots of $x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2$?

I tried using the quadratic formula:

$$ x_{1,2} = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt {4a^2-4b^2}}{2} = {a \pm \sqrt {a^2-b^2}} = a\pm \sqrt{a-b}\sqrt{a+b}$$

I tried to represent each root as $x+iy$ but got stuck along the way.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are real?

Comment: Yes, $a,b$ are real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten as
$$(x-a)^2=-b^2\iff x-a=\pm ib$$
so the roots are $x_{1,2}=a\pm ib$.

---

The quadratic formula also gives the right answer, but it should be
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{2a\pm\sqrt{4a^2-4(a^2+b^2)}}2=a\pm\sqrt{-b^2}=a\pm ib$$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 + b^2 = 0 \Rightarrow (x - a)^2 = -b^2 \Rightarrow x = a \pm ib.$